# Handling interruptions while playing audio using OpenAL, RemoteIO and AVPlayer simultaneously

Tags: ios, core-audio, avplayer, openal, remoteio

I am developing an app that requires playing audio using OpenAL, RemoteIO and AVPlayer simultaneously. I am also handling interruptions the way it is mentioned according to Apple's guidelines here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Playback of RemoteIO and AVPlayer are getting resumed properly. However playback of OpenAL gets muted.

For OpenAL, I am resetting the context when the interruption ends like this:

```
alcMakeContextCurrent (myContext);
```

Playback resumes properly when only OpenAL playback is happening **or** when OpenAL playback is happening along with RemoteIO. However, if I'm playing audio using OpenAL, RemoteIO and AVPlayer simultaneously, on resumption, OpenAL playback gets muted. What could be going wrong?

Comment: The order in which you shutdown OpenAL, RemoteIO and AVPlayer before an interruption may be important.

Comment: @hotpaw2 What should be the right order?